# Change background DIV depending on the time of day

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

All my question is in the title: How can I change my background DIV depending on the time of day?

I tried traditional Javascript :

```
var d = new Date(event.starthourid),
    h = d.getHours(event.starthourid),
    i;

    if (h < 06) i = "night.jpg";
    else if (h < 11) i = "sunrise.jpg";
    else if (h < 18) i = "sunny.jpg";
    else if (h < 21) i = "sunset.jpg";
    else i = "night.jpg";

document.getElementById("header-item").style.backgroundImage = "url("+i+")";
```

But since I encountered `ng-class` and `ng-style`, I understand I've been doing it wrong.  How can I accomplish the above the "Angular" way?

Comment: You already have good answers to your question, so instead of adding back in irrelevant information about Firebase, you should accept one of the answers.  If you need help specifically with Firebase, then you can ask another question.

Comment: I've specifically Firebase, but you delete all mention of it with no reason previously (5 minutes after I ask my first question)

Comment: You have two different problems, so you're much more likely to get good answers if you ask two different questions.  Looks like you got an answer to your first part (changing the background), so try asking a new question about the problem you have retrieving your Firebase data.

Comment: I was afraid to "spam" issues, as much for me . I will create a new question . Thank for your help !

Comment: The link of new discussion : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31250609/angularfire-impossible-to-recover-the-time-entered-by-the-user-in-database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'd be better served with ngClass in this case, so you don't have to remember where those styles are coming from if you want to update an image location for example.  And, of course, both ngClass and ngStyle are directives, so they are the right place to do DOM manipulation in AngularJS, as stated @daniel-beck.

Here's an example of how to use ngClass:

```js
var app = angular.module('demo', []);

app.controller('MyTimeCtrl', function($scope){
    var h = new Date().getHours();
    if (h <= 18) {
      $scope.time="day";
    } else {
      $scope.time="night";
    }
  
});
```

```css
.main {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100px;
}
.night {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.day {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="MyTimeCtrl" class="main" ng-class="time">
    <p>It's {{time}}!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's work with current time ! But I want to retrieve the time that the user has entered the database ( I use Firebase for information) "starthourid" .
Any solution ?

Comment: Just like you'd get any data from Firebase using AngularFire.  Create a reference to your firebase, then retrieve your data.  In this case, you can use a private function to get the time from the object you get back based on your starthourid, and then set it to the scope variable that you want to use.

Comment: Or is your question more about how to actually get the data from firebase?

Comment: Yeah, I can retrieve my data in HTML, but with your code I'm in difficulty (And sorry for my bad english ..)

Comment: Your English is great.  So, you can get the data.  That's good.  Can you update your question with the way you get the data and give a sample of what it looks like?  Then I can give you a clear answer.

Comment: Actually, I see why Mike is trying to keep the question to one topic.  Go ahead and post another question.  I'll answer you there.

Comment: I will create another question, I give you link here when it's done ! Thanks all folks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82515/discussion-between-yngdev31-and-jme11).

Answer (score 3):

Angular requires a completely different mindset from what you're used to -- instead of drawing the DOM and then digging around in it with e.g. getElementById to find elements and Do Stuff to them, you create directives which, when rendered in the DOM, Do Stuff to themselves.

So for this example you'd do something like

```
.directive('myHeaderItem', function () {
    return {
        template: '<div style="background-image: url({{bgImage}})">...</div>',
        link: function (scope, element) {

        var h = new Date().getHours();
        var i;

        if (h < 06) i = "night.jpg";
        else if (h < 11) i = "sunrise.jpg";
        else if (h < 18) i = "sunny.jpg";
        else if (h < 21) i = "sunset.jpg";
        else i = "night.jpg";

        scope.bgImage = i; // to pass values to the directive template, attach them to scope
    };
})
```

...and then in your HTML you would just include `<div my-header-item></div>`.

Followup: As jme11 pointed out in comments, a better coding style would have been to set a css class from within the directive, rather than an image URL, i.e. have your directive template be `'<div class="{{foo}}">'` (setting foo to the css classname that draws the background image you want.)

Alternatively, you could move more of the logic into the template itself rather than the directive (it wouldn't make much sense to do this in this case but for completeness' sake here's how you would do it:)

```
.directive('myHeaderItem', function () {
    return {
        template: '<div ng-class="{
            'sunrise': h>=6 && h<11, 
            'sunny': h>=11 && h<18, 
            'sunset': h>=18 && h<21,
            'night': h>=21 || h<6
        }">...</div>', // will result in i.e. <div class="sunny">...</div>
        link: function (scope, element) {
        scope.h = new Date().getHours();
    };
})
```

Comment: Excellent point, but why create a custom directive when you've got the built in ones that the OP asked about?  Or, did you mean this as more generic example to show that you can create custom directives?

Comment: Perhaps just a difference in coding style -- I depend heavily on custom directives for all but the most trivial cases. (which, arguably, the OP's question was, but it seemed like he could use a leg up from there :)   I try to avoid modifying scope directly from inside controllers as a general rule, and instead use them only as containers for shared functions the directives can call as needed.   Perhaps that's idiosyncratic but I find I have a lot fewer accidental-scope-leakage issues to debug this way...

Comment: Yeah, those are very good reasons, but now you have an unintended dependency in the image location.  I'm not even sure how I'd test for it.

Comment: ng-class instead of url({{var}}) would have been a better choice, true; I blindly copied that from the original.  I'll update my answer, thank you!

Comment: Anyone have delete a lot of word in my first question .. Anyway, thank for your time, but I don't want retrieve the current date, I want to retrieve the time that the user has entered the database ( I use Firebase for information). The hour is stocked in "starthourid" ... Thanks

Comment: YngDev31 that wouldn't change much of either answer you've received, you would simply bind your database value instead of using the current time.  (If you need help with that that's probably a different question. I'm not familiar with firebase but I imagine https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/ would be where to start)

Comment: I will try with your solution and jme11's solution, I'll be back in few minutes !